# save sequences from NCBI in fasta format using a list of IDs in excel

Tags: parsing, bioinformatics, biopython

I am fairly new using python and I love it. However I am stuck with this problem and I hope you could give me a hind about what I am missing.

I have a list of gene IDs in an excel file and I am trying to use xrld and biopython to retrieve sequences and save (in fasta format) my results in to a text document. so far, my code allow me to see the results in the shell but it only save the last sequence in a document.

this is my code:

```
import xlrd
import re
book = xlrd.open_workbook('ids.xls')
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for rx in range(sh.nrows):
    if sh.row(rx)[0].value:
        from Bio import Entrez
        from Bio import SeqIO
        Entrez.email = "mail@xxx.com"
        in_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", rettype="fasta", id=sh.row(rx)[0].value)
        record = SeqIO.parse(in_handle, "fasta")
        for record in SeqIO.parse(in_handle, "fasta"):
            print record.format("fasta")
        out_handle = open("example.txt", "w")
        SeqIO.write(record, out_handle, "fasta")
        in_handle.close()
        out_handle.close()
```

As I mentioned, the file "example.txt", only have the last sequence (in fasta format) that shows the shell.

could anyone please help me how to get al the sequences I retrieve from NCBI in the same document?

Thank you very much

Antonio

Answer (score 0):

I am also fairly new to python and also love it! this is my first attempt at answering a question, but maybe it is because of your loop structure and the 'w' mode? perhaps try changing ("example.txt", "w") to append mode ("example.txt", "a") as below?

```
import xlrd
import re
book = xlrd.open_workbook('ids.xls')
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for rx in range(sh.nrows):
    if sh.row(rx)[0].value:
        from Bio import Entrez
        from Bio import SeqIO
        Entrez.email = "mail@xxx.com"
        in_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", rettype="fasta", id=sh.row(rx)[0].value)
        record = SeqIO.parse(in_handle, "fasta")
        for record in SeqIO.parse(in_handle, "fasta"):
            print record.format("fasta")
        out_handle = open("example.txt", "a")
        SeqIO.write(record, out_handle, "fasta")
        in_handle.close()
        out_handle.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly there my friends!

The *main* problem is that your For loop keeps closing the file each loop. I also fixed some minor issues that should just speed up the code (e.g. you kept importing Bio each loop).

***Use this new code:***

```
out_handle = open("example.txt", "w")
import xlrd
import re
from Bio import Entrez
from Bio import SeqIO
book = xlrd.open_workbook('ids.xls')
sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
for rx in range(sh.nrows):
    if sh.row(rx)[0].value:
        Entrez.email = "mail@xxx.com"
        in_handle = Entrez.efetch(db="nucleotide", rettype="fasta", id=rx)
        record = SeqIO.parse(in_handle, "fasta")
        SeqIO.write(record, out_handle, "fasta")
        in_handle.close()
out_handle.close()
```

**If it still errors, It must be a problem in your excel file. Send this to me if the error still persists and I will help :)**